# Dedicate part of Jetty Thread pool to specific endpoints

Tags: java, jax-rs, jetty, threadpool, jersey-2.0

I am using Java/Jetty/Jaxrs. I have an web application(API) with several endpoints. But one particular endpoint has high usage. Is it possible to dedicate more jetty worker threads to that endpoint alone? Is there a way to split the threadpool per endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

That is accomplished with the [`QoSFilter`](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/qos-filter.html).

You would allow you to specify which URL Endpoints should have different rules for processing.

Comment: Great. But can you give an example of how to use it without web.xml file?

Comment: The `WEB-INF/web.xml` is required to use the `QoSFilter` directly.  In a typical usage, you'll wind up creating multiple entries, on different url endpoints, with different configurations.

Comment: In this case i am using Jersey/JaxRs ResourceConfig class.

Comment: Jersey / JaxRs is just a single Servlet on a Servlet container.  It definitely supports `WEB-INF/web.xml` and even proper embedded-jetty, lots of examples of this kind of setup on stackoverflow (and other places online)